Weak Convergence in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ implies Almost Everywhere Convergence
CLAIM

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence such that $f_n \rightharpoonup 0$ in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Does this imply that $f_n \overset{ae}{\to} 0$?

WORK DONE SO FAR
I have shown that the claim is false if we replace almost everywhere convergence with uniform convergence: indeed, one can consider a sequence of functions that moves the mass to infinity.
I have also shown that under our hypothesis $f_n \to 0$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$: indeed, $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2) \hookrightarrow L^2({\mathbb{R}^2})$ is compact, therefore it sends weakly convergent sequences into strongly convergent ones. This means that there must be a subsequence converging almost everywhere to $0$ and thus our only hope for a counter-example lies in a sequence with a "double pointwise behaviour" but with the "same weak behaviour".

Any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself more clearly!
